# Alternative to artifactorycleanup plugin for OSS

Tags: artifactory

My organisation currently uses the OSS version of Artifactory which means we cannot use the artifactorycleanup plugin as this is designed for Pro only. Does anyone out there know of any alternatives to this plugin that do the same thing and also have an option of doing a dry run before deleting anything?
Happy to take a look at anything from jfrog or a 3rd party if needs be.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe OSS solution supports AQL queries, right?

If it does - you can use the tool https://github.com/devopshq/artifactory-cleanup (which we posted as open source project)

The recent release support YAML configuration, so you can define cleanup policies for Artifactory like this:

```yaml
# artifactory-cleanup.yaml
artifactory-cleanup:
  server: https://repo.example.com/artifactory
  # $VAR is auto populated from environment variables
  user: $ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME
  password: $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD

  policies:
    - name: Remove all files from repo-name-here older then 7 days
      rules:
        - rule: Repo
          name: "reponame"
        - rule: DeleteOlderThan
          days: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move to [JFrog Platform Cloud](https://jfrog.com/start-free/#saas), starting with the free plan, which gives you what you have with Artifactory OSS and much more, including [JFrog Pipelines](https://jfrog.com/pipelines/).

You can use Pipelines together with the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) to create your cleanup tasks -

- Use [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language) to find the artifacts to cleanup
- Use the JFrog CLI to execute your queries and operations on Artifactory
  (e.g. see [deleting files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DeletingFiles) - by query, supports also dry-run)
- Use an [IncomingWebhook](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/IncomingWebhook) resource to [trigger the pipeline via HTTP POST](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Triggering+Pipelines+and+Steps#TriggeringPipelinesandSteps-TriggeringOnaWebhook)
- Use a [CronTrigger](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/CronTrigger) resource to [trigger the pipeline on a time schedule](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Triggering+Pipelines+and+Steps#TriggeringPipelinesandSteps-TriggeringOnaTimeSchedule)
- Trigger the cleanup pipeline manually with [custom variables](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Triggering+a+Run+with+Custom+Parameters), e.g. `DRY_RUN=true`

But it is up to you to implement it all in your pipeline.

P.S.

1. For reference, the mentioned user plugin is [Artifactory Artifact Cleanup User Plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup)
2. See blog post: [Artifactory Cleanup Best Practices](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-cleanup-best-practices/)

Comment: Thanks @yinon, unfortunately the organisation I work in won't change from their current setup (even if they were open to this, it would be a very long drawn-out process lol). Is there anything else that can be done without changing any of our setup?

Comment: For built-in cleanup features in Artifactory you can check this blog post: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-cleanup-best-practices/ , but I guess you probably already seen it. I'm not aware of external tools that can accomplish what you are looking for out-of-the-box. You can use the JFrog CLI and implement the cleanup policy on your own, running it on some other execution service.
See https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory